# Matlab - comparison of entropy of histograms

Tags: matlab, entropy

I'm trying to understand the entropy of a vector. I started by generating a sample of size 1000000 from a normal distribution with mean 130 and variance 1:

```
kk=normrnd(130,20,1000000,1);
kk=uint8(kk);%did this or else the result was 0
entropy(kk)
```

The `imhist` of kk is:

[image]

The entropy result is 6.3686

Then I generated a sample of size 1000 from a normal distribution with mean 130 and variance 1 following the same steps as before to get a noisier distribution, here is the histogram:

[image]

And the entropy is 6.2779. So it seems the noisier the distribution the smaller the entropy. I calculated the entropies for other sample sizes of a normal distribution with same mean and variance and it changes according to this. But am I right? Is this the right way to compare entropies of histogram distributions?

**[EDITION]**

After what obchardon said I investigated a bit more. This distribution:

```
kk1=normrnd(130,75,1000000,1);%entropy=7.6983
```

gives me a bigger entropy than:

```
kk2=normrnd(130,20,1000000,1);%entropy=6.3686
```

but this one's entropy is smaller than `kk1` and `kk2`:

```
kka2=normrnd(130,150,100000,1);%entropy=6.1660
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entropy formula is biased for small vector:

For example:

We generate a 10x1 normally distributed vector:

```
n = 10

kk=normrnd(130,20,n,1);
kk=uint8(kk);
```

Now we calculate the entropy:

```
kk = im2double(kk);
P = hist(kk(:), linspace(0, 1, 256)); 
P = P(:); P = P(P(:)>0); %we need to delete the value where P = 0, because log(0) = Inf.
P = P/n;
E = -sum(P.*log2(P))
```

So in this example the entropy will never be higher than `-sum(n*(1/n)*log2(1/n))` `= 3.32` ! (worst case where each kk value are differents)

So @TasosPapastylianou is right: the entropy is a function of (only) its variance but only when [image: n-->inf].

[image: maximumentropyvalue]

[image]

Comment: Good point. I was thrown off by the whole "gaussian vs noisy gaussian" comparison and disregarded the effect from the discrete nature of a vector. One of the important differences of absolute entropy vs differential entropy! Thanks for catching that. (also, I think you meant to say `-(n*(1/n)*log2(1/n))` above)

Comment: Ok so I tried what you say in various distributions. The entropy value decreases as the variance increases, but only when the sides around the mean are above 0. Else, this makes the entropy value go up as there are some values that have the same probability 0 (or intensity 0 if we speak about histograms). Is this right?

Comment: In this PARTICULAR CASE the entropy will decrease if the variance increase a lot, because you apply this line `kk=uint8(kk)` so of course if your variance = 1000 (for example) almost all your value are going to be = 0 or = 255 (so the entropy artificially decrease) ! So I recommand you to use another formula that can take into account value < 0 and value > 255, and this time the entropy will always increase if the variance increase.

Comment: And how can I compare the entropy between non gaussian distributions? For example, histograms of real grayscale images?

Comment: If all the value are between 0-255 then this code Will work. However if you have value < 0 or > 255 then you have to use int16 (or int32... Depending on Your value)  instead of uint8 . Then adjust m'y code to calculate the enthropy (since the built in fonction enthropy Can only manage uint8 array)

Answer (score 0):

Your conclusion that "the noisier the distribution the smaller the entropy" is incorrect. For a gaussian distributed random variable, the entropy is a function of its variance; I'm guessing that your 2nd vector simply happens to have slightly smaller variance (which, also seems to be the case visually), but other than that their entropies are pretty similar.

(have a look at [Bishop](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387310732) p.52, fig 1.30 for a fuller explanation)

Comment: PS. That's not a variance of 1.

Comment: I can be wrong but I think that the length of the vector has an effect on the entropy value. (cf. my answer)